# Uncontrolled iteration in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

Thats my code:

```
var randomCoord = function(cells) {
    var step = $('.workplace').innerWidth()/cells;
    var xCord = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (cells+1)))*step;
    var yCord = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (cells+1)))*step;
    if(plants.length != 0) {
        for (var i=0; i<plants.length; i++) {
            if (plants[i].left != xCord && plants[i].top != yCord) {
                plants.push({"top": yCord, "left": xCord});
            }
        }
    } else {
        plants.push({"top": yCord, "left": xCord});
    }
};
var multiplayer = function(func, endIteration, cells) {
    for (var i=0; i<endIteration; i++) {
        func(cells);
    };
};
    multiplayer(randomCoord, 5, 10) // will iterate diferent times
```

Function, multiplayer have to run "randomCoords" 5 times, but it's not working. Why quantity of iteration is uncontroled? How can I fix it?

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: please post your jsfiddle ,and html

Comment: I got array with difrent length, it's not length which equal 'endIteration'

Comment: the calls are fine - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/c36nJ/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `for` loop in `randomCoord()` is supposed to be only pushing an entry into the array if the coordinates don't already exist in the array, but that isn't how your logic works.  Instead, you check each and every item in the array and if it's not equal to that item in the array, you push it and you do that for each item in the array so you end up with lots of duplicates in the array (exactly what you're trying to prevent).

So, the first time you call randomCoord, you get one item.  The next time you call it, you get two items.  The third time you call it you get 4 items, then 8, then 16.  This is a fairly simple logic error.

If you just want to add one unique item each time you call randomCoord, then you could use logic like this:

```
var randomCoord = function(cells) {
    var step = $('.workplace').innerWidth()/cells;
    var xCord = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (cells+1)))*step;
    var yCord = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (cells+1)))*step;
    var found = false;
    for (var i=0; i<plants.length; i++) {
        if (plants[i].left == xCord && plants[i].top == yCord) {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!found) {
        plants.push({"top": yCord, "left": xCord});
    }
};
```

Note, you don't need the separate `if (plants.length != 0)` because the `for` loop already checks that and our new `found` variable handles the case where the array is initially empty.

If you happen to generate a coordinate conflict, this will add no item on that function call though the odds of generating two conflicting random values are fairly low as long as `cells*step` is a decent size number (the range of your random number generator).  If you want to try it again in that case, then you need another loop to try again if a conflict is found.

Comment: What if I return randomCoord in case if I find cordinate conflict?

Comment: @user2971752 - yes, you could just return if you find a conflict.